# Flow chart - arrows connecting nodes

Tags: tikz-arrows

I an new to TikZ, and having some trouble making the connecting arrows between the nodes...

Here is my code:

```
 % Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20,  
text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner      sep=0pt]
 \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,text width=8em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em]
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture} [node distance = 2.5cm, auto]
\node [block] (init) {Temperering av melk};
\node [block, below of=init] (init1) {Kulturtilsetning};
\node [block, below of=init1] (init2) {Formodning};
\node [block, below of=init2] (init3) {L{\o}petilsetning};
\node [block, below of=init3] (init4) {Koagulering};
\node [block, below of=init4] (init5) {Skj{\ae}ring};
\node [block, below of=init5] (init6) {R{\o}ring}; 
\node [block, right of=init,node distance=5cm] (init7) {Forming};          
\node [block, right of=init1,node distance=5cm] (init8){Drenering/Syrning};    
\node [block, right of=init2,node distance=5cm] (init9) {Vending};
\node [block, right of=init3,node distance=5cm] (init10) {Salting};
\node [block, right of=init4,node distance=5cm] (init11) {Modning};
\node [block, right of=init5,node distance=5cm] (init12) {Prikking};
\node [block, right of=init6,node distance=5cm] (init13) {Pakking}; 
\node [block,right of=init7,node distance=5cm] (init14) {Ettermodning};     
\path [line] (init) -- (init1);
\path [line] (init1) -- (init2);
\path [line] (init2) -- (init3);
\path [line] (init3) -- (init4);
\path [line] (init4) -- (init5);
\path [line] (init5) -- (init6);
\path [line, rounded corners] (init6) |- (init7);  
\path [line] (init7) -- (init8);
\path [line] (init8) -- (init9);
\path [line] (init9) -- (init10); 
\path [line] (init10) -- (init11);
\path [line] (init11) -- (init12);
\path [line] (init12) -- (init13);
\path [line, rounded corners] (init13) -| (init14);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

This is my output, where the red lines/arrows represents the arrows that I want to include.

[image]

Does anyone know how to make these arrows?

Answer (score 4):

You just have to change a little the line specifications.

You had, for example:

```
\path [line, rounded corners] (init6) |- (init7);
```

This line tells Ti*k*Z to go up (`|`) then right (`-`) from `init6` to `init7`.

The first thing to change is that you want to go right, then up, so `-|`. But only this will glue the vertical part of the arrow to the boxes, so we tell Ti*k*Z to start from the right edge of `init6` (`(init6.east)`), go `1cm` to the right (`-- ++ (1cm,0)`), then go up and right to the left edge of `init7` (`|- (init7.west)`):

```
\path [line, rounded corners] (init6.east) -- ++ (1cm,0) |- (init7.west);
```

The same applies to the other arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
 % Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20,  
text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner      sep=0pt]
 \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,text width=8em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em]
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture} [node distance = 2.5cm, auto]
\node [block] (init) {Temperering av melk};
\node [block, below of=init] (init1) {Kulturtilsetning};
\node [block, below of=init1] (init2) {Formodning};
\node [block, below of=init2] (init3) {L{\o}petilsetning};
\node [block, below of=init3] (init4) {Koagulering};
\node [block, below of=init4] (init5) {Skj{\ae}ring};
\node [block, below of=init5] (init6) {R{\o}ring}; 
\node [block, right of=init,node distance=5cm] (init7) {Forming};          
\node [block, right of=init1,node distance=5cm] (init8){Drenering/Syrning};    
\node [block, right of=init2,node distance=5cm] (init9) {Vending};
\node [block, right of=init3,node distance=5cm] (init10) {Salting};
\node [block, right of=init4,node distance=5cm] (init11) {Modning};
\node [block, right of=init5,node distance=5cm] (init12) {Prikking};
\node [block, right of=init6,node distance=5cm] (init13) {Pakking}; 
\node [block,right of=init7,node distance=5cm] (init14) {Ettermodning};     
\path [line] (init) -- (init1);
\path [line] (init1) -- (init2);
\path [line] (init2) -- (init3);
\path [line] (init3) -- (init4);
\path [line] (init4) -- (init5);
\path [line] (init5) -- (init6);
\path [line, rounded corners] (init6.east) -- ++ (1cm,0) |- (init7.west);  
\path [line] (init7) -- (init8);
\path [line] (init8) -- (init9);
\path [line] (init9) -- (init10); 
\path [line] (init10) -- (init11);
\path [line] (init11) -- (init12);
\path [line] (init12) -- (init13);
\path [line, rounded corners] (init13.east) -- ++ (1cm,0) |- (init14.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]